# Can't use my apple ID balance

Tags: apple-id

I have $25 in my account and can see the balance. I am trying to buy something that is $24.95. When I try to buy it, it tells me I have insufficient funds and wants me to change my billing information to a credit card. I have clicked on None and it won't apply my $25 and keeps wanting me to add a credit card which I don't want to do. How do I purchase using my balance that is already in my account???

Comment: Is that amount including tax and shipping?

Comment: have you tried singing out and back in again ;) ?